# Log each input element's name attribute to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a HTML form of which I would like to log each input element's name attribute to console.

I've tried following but it just returns some kind of (jquery) object which is bloated with "stuff".

```
$('input').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: It should return attribute name as string for all input nodes, please provide sample to replicate your issue. FYI, `this.name` would work the same and `$(':input')` would target all form controls. BTW, would it be better you posted `it just returns some kind of (jquery) object which is bloated with "stuff"`???

Comment: isn't there a `console.log($(this).attr('name').value)`?

Comment: I am assuming you are running this all in the console. Are you sure you are not looking at the output of the line `$('input')` running?

Comment: @DJBurb, no, [.attr( attributeName )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets the value of an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you posted will, in fact, return all values for all inputs that have the property 'name' set. And after doing that, it will return the entire array of elements that matched your selector, 'input', which might be what you're calling an 'object bloated with stuff'.

Comment: So, what would return just the value of the name attribute? I already did this with a regex but since this seemed like a trivial task I would like know the facts why the script works like it does and not in the the way that it was designed.

Comment: You can use the `map` javascript native function, with exactly the same code as the one you posted just replace the word `each` by `map`.

The reason behind jquery doing this to provide method chaning, all jquery functions return a jquery set so you can chain functions on them.

`$('div').addClass('wut').removeClass('fud');`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.. 
this can catch every form submitted and it will log all values submitted in a form...
make sure that you delete this before you deploy your web. for security issues....

```
 $(form).on("submit",function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("FORM:"+$(this).serialize());

     });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this mate.

```
var i,
    input = $('input');


for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(input.eq(i).attr('name'));
}
```

A for loop is much quicker and reliable.